# Xamarin forms retrieve student details Id on button click event handler

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I would like to create a set of dynamic buttons based on a list of students. In the winforms days I would have had the tag property to store the ID of the student for easy retrieval.

But in Xamrain Forms I do not have that so how would I retrieve the student ID on my button click event handler to be able to retrieve the correct student Id details?

Also, how does one gain access to the current button the student clicked on in winforms you would have accessed the array of buttons?

```
public async void CheckInButtons()
{
    List<Booking>  myList = new List<Booking>(); //your list here
    var test = DayNumber;
    myList =await  api.GetAllBookingsForDay(DayNumber,Helpers.Dates.GetDateZeroTime(DateTime.Now).AddDays(1));


    //  checkinButtons.Children.Clear(); //just in case so you can call this code several times np..
    foreach (var item in myList)
    {
        string firstname = "Dan Check IN";
        string lastname = "Button";
        var btn = new Button()
        {
                
            BackgroundColor = Color.Blue,
            TextColor = Color.White,
            Text = firstname + " " + lastname,
               
            };
        btn.Clicked += Btn_Clicked; 
        checkinButtons.Children.Add(btn);
    }

}
```

Here is my button click:

```
private void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var item = e.ToString();
        /// I need to get the student details here? How
        /// I also want to be able to disable the current button of the student 
        /// after they clicked it in winforms u could have goto the index number of the button how in xamrain?

        btnGotoExercise.IsVisible = true;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the idea of using `AutomationId`, else you could set the BindingContext of the `Button`:

```cs
    foreach (var item in myList)
    {
        string firstname = "Dan Check IN";
        string lastname = "Button";
        var btn = new Button()
        {
                
            BackgroundColor = Color.Blue,
            TextColor = Color.White,
            Text = firstname + " " + lastname,
               
            };
        btn.Clicked += Btn_Clicked; 
        btn.BindingContext = item; // add this here
        checkinButtons.Children.Add(btn);
    }
```

Then on click

```cs
private void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var item = ((Button)sender).BindingContext as Booking;

        btnGotoExercise.IsVisible = true;

}
```

I would probably use a ListView though for something like this as the cell has a reference to the "Booking" that it is rendering.

Comment: Thanks james its nice example many thanks for all your hard work its David from twitter